# Wait for JavaFX runtime to be ready

Tags: java, javafx

> I’m no longer looking for an answer to this question; I used a workaround. See the [temporary_fx_logger](https://github.com/ogallagher/temp_fx_logger/blob/7116563da372830af24147c819b5dc9fabb33f46/src/ogallagher/temp_fx_logger/System.java#L68-L115) project for real-life context, where `System.Out.init` handles the console window.

I have a utility class whose dedicated gui window I want to load when the parent main javafx application (runnable main class that `extends Application`) launches.

Below are example classes to illustrate my approach:

```java
package owengall.diagnostics;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

class Diagnostics {
    private static Stage gui;
    
    static {
        // initialize diagnostics window on javafx thread
        // throws illegal state exception because javafx runtime is not ready :(
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gui = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sayHello() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            /* pseudocode
            addMessageToGui("hello from Diagnostics.sayHello");
            */
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package owengall.diagnostics.test;

import javafx.application.Application;

import owengall.diagnostics.Diagnostics;

class TestDriver extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello from TestDriver.main");
        Diagnostics.sayHello();

        launch(args);
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("hello from TestDriver.start");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add a diagnostics window to any parent javafx app, but am not sure how to have `Diagnostics` wait until the javafx runtime is ready before deploying its window.

Comment: What do you mean by "parent" in this context? How are you planning on using this? Create and post a [mre] showing what you intend to do with this class.

Comment: @James_D edited question to include example `TestDriver` and some filler code. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Why don't you just check if the gui has been initialized in `sayHello()` and initialize it if not? Then move the call to `sayHello()` to the `start()` method, instead of the `main()` method (and get rid of the `Platform.runLater(...)` calls). The `start()` method is, by design, where you start up a JavaFX application, and since your `Diagnostics.sayHello()` method is a GUI call, that's the proper place to call it.

Comment: .. and don't use static scope for anything, except you know _exactly_ what you are doing :)

Comment: @James_D I want to be able to run `Diagnostics.sayHello` from any thread (even non-gui), so that’s why I have the `Platform.runLater` calls. In the actual program I’ll check whether I’m already on the javafx thread. Per `start` instead of `main`, is there no way to be able to run `sayHello` in `main`?

Comment: Edited to correct misremembered method name `run` for `Application.start`.

Comment: I don't really understand the requirements, so I can't really answer. Why would you want to run this from any thread? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: This feels like a less than ideal design.  Trying to “spy” on an application to add your own diagnostic window is unnecessarily complex.  I’m not sure what the actual intent is, but I suspect a regular public method that JavaFX applications can call explicitly would be a better approach.